# Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use. See the server log for details

Tags: tomcat, netbeans-8.2

Hola como puedo arreglar este error en netbeans?.

Answer (score 1):

El error indica que el puerto 8080 ya esta en uso.

Aunque no lo haz explicado parece que tu error se presenta al ejecutar Tomcat desde Netbeans. Para resolver el problema tienes dos opciones:

1. Ver que aplicación esta usando el puerto 8080 (esto depende del Sistema Operativo donde estés trabajando) y bajar el programa que usa el puerto.
2. Ir al archivo de configuración del tomcat server.xml buscar donde se indica 8080 y cambiarlo por otro número de puerto que no se este ocupando en el equipo.

Comment: gracias amigo pero pues la verdad ya he intentado todo eso que mencionas. Por ejemplo, si cambio el puerto 8080 y despues de correr el proyecto en netbeans. Me sale como error, que Tomcat a fallado. Incluso vi otro metodo en internet que decia que dentro de la carpeta de bin en tomcat, debia ejecutar un comando en la terminal llamada shutdown.bat y aun asi ni eso me ha funcionado. Lo que he estado pensando es  en cambiar de servidor si es que existieran otras alternativas.

Comment: shutdown.bat termina el proceso del tomcat. Puedes ponernos el server.xml y unas capturas de la pantalla de como esta configurado el tomcat en netbeans.